# issues writing to a file when redirecting output from another file

Tags: c++, linux, system-calls, file-descriptor

i was tasked with writing a 'small shell' program, but i have faced issues when i am trying to redirect output, i would love any help.

first off, i would say the most strange thing to me in this matter: the following commands give different prints, when i run them in bash:

```
./myshell < infile
./myshell < infile > outfile
```

one of them (the first one) manages to write to the file when redirecting input, but the second one only creates the file, but i believe still directs the output to 'outfile' (although i'm not sure at this point, to be honest)

here is my code regarding the redirection:

```
    int stdout_fd = dup(1); //keep the original output file descriptor
    int fd;
    fd = open(end.c_str(), O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666); //end is the file name
    //fd is not -1 here
    dup2(fd,1);
    executeCommand(start.c_str()); //goes to other function to do print something, using std::cout << ...
    close(1);
    dup2(stdout_fd, 1);
    close(stdout_fd);
```

it's a fairly simple code - keep the file descriptor, open the file you want to write to, put it in the stdout's file descriptor and restore the original file descriptor. that's all.

however, it doesnt work!
the two lines i wrote up give different output (the first one prints the expected output), but i cant understand where!

in 'infile' i write to a file called 'my_pid', on the first one it's being written properly and has the right data, but on the second command the file is indeed created if not exists, but is left empty - the data is printed to the 'outfile' as it seems.

would love any help understand where this issue originates from and what can I do to fix it. thanks!

Comment: Recommendation: Back up the code and then carve it down to a [mre]. If you off people a simple path to investigating your code and testing proposed solutions, you are orders of magnitude more likely to get an answer or at least usable comments.

Comment: The default redirection in `bash` is to use the standard streams, such as standard input and standard output.  When you specify the redirection symbols, `bash` will do its best to redirect the input or output accordingly.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I see, ty, it would still change where I'm writing to inside my program? I mean, sorry if I'm wrong, but I'm trying to explicitly write to a specific file here, bash would change it too? Is there any way to get around that?

Comment: IMHO, your best direction is to have your program use streams, instead of named streams like `std::cout`.  If a function has a `std::istream&` parameter, you can pass it `std::cin`, or a file string or a string stream or any kind of stream derived from `std::istream`.

Comment: For example, your command parser function should have a `std::istream` as the parameter.  Thus if the User doesn't specify a redirection, you can pass `std::cin`.  Otherwise open the given file and pass that to the command parser function.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews How does that help? His shell is running external commands, they can't access the C++ streams of the shell. They simply inherit stdin, stdout, and stderr file descriptors.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews thank you, but I'm afraid I can't use that (as far as I'm aware) on the exrecise on uni. I heard some other people have used the same functions and managed to do that. That's what I'm trying to achieve here.

Comment: If the shell redirects the output of the commands it executes, the output redirection of the shell itself shouldn't have any effect.

Comment: `outfile` should only contain the shell's prompts, not the output from executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

After a few more hours of trying to figure it out I think I've finally found the source of the issue - there was no flushing.

As far as I understand, flushing normally happens automatically when using `<< endl` afterwards. In the code above I used

```
executeCommand(start.c_str());
```

but when it tried to print, the prints didn't end with `<< endl;`

The fix, in short, is to add the flushing to cout before proceeding, in my case it's as simple as

```
SmallShell::getInstance().executeCommand(start.c_str());
std::cout << flush;
```

however I guess adding `<<endl` after every print will do the same.

I still don't fully get what's the buffer that needs to be flushed exactly, but that seems like what's caused the issue.